# Nginx: Rewrite/Redirect URLs in a subdirectory to root

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, directory

I want to rewrite or redirect any URLs inside a subdirectory to root, like so:

**www.site.com/subdirectory/item => www.site.com/item**

I tried this, but doesn't seem to work properly:

```
location /subdirectory {
    rewrite ^/subdirectory(/.*)$ $1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
rewrite ^/subdirectory(.*) /$1 last;
```

What you have *requires* a '/' after '/subdirectory'.

Also - a quick hack would be to make a symlink in the document root:

```
ln -s . subdirectory
```

Comment: Thanks, Dan, but unfortunately it didn't work. Got a 404 response still.

Comment: @RaphaelSuzuki - Any luck?  Did you try the symlink method?